# How to add data dynamic on recyclerView and save the data?

Tags: android

I want to save the data when user input edit text.

It can show on recyclerView and the app can show it again when the app had restarted.

I try to user sharepreference, i can let the recyclerView shows the data when user input edit text.

But when I want to save the data and get it , the layout will let my app crash.

I found the crash code is 
    String getUserInputBlood = preferences.getString("uerInputBlood", "");

How can i fix it ? any help will be grateful.

layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_blood_sugar_report"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.huaweb_system.taiwanuniversityhome.BloodSugarReportActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editBloodSugar"
        android:text="543"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendBlood"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerBloodReport"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

activity:

```
public class BloodSugarReportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerBloodReport;
    private BloodSugarReportAdapter myAdapter;
    private List<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    private EditText editBloodSugar;
    private Button sendBlood;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blood_sugar_report);

        editBloodSugar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBloodSugar);


        sendBlood=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendBlood);
        sendBlood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String uerInputBlood = editBloodSugar.getText().toString();
                preferences=getSharedPreferences("uerInputBlood",MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor=preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("uerInputBlood",uerInputBlood);
                editor.commit();
                //show user input edit text successful-------------
                listData.add(uerInputBlood);
            }
        });
        //i try to use getString to get it that i saved.-----------
        //it will crash
        String getUserInputBlood = preferences.getString("uerInputBlood", "");
        listData.add(getUserInputBlood);

        recyclerBloodReport = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerBloodReport);
        recyclerBloodReport.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        myAdapter=new BloodSugarReportAdapter(this,listData);
        recyclerBloodReport.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //of course , it's not working from here
        String getUserInputBlood = preferences.getString("uerInputBlood", "");
        listData.add(getUserInputBlood);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to move "preferences=getSharedPreferences("uerInputBlood",MODE_PRIVATE);" outside OnClickListener and before prefercences.getString(). Hope it help!

Comment: thanks @I_A_Mok  . It works for me !

but i found i just save the last data , how could i save all of it ?

Comment: You will need something different from `SharedPreferences` to store all list values, e.g. storing them to a [SQLite database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Comment: So if i use the SharedPreferences , i just can save the data one by one , if i want to save all of them and get it , i really need to change to use SQLite database , right ?

Comment: I try to save the data in List<String> from the sharedPreference putString , and sharedPreference getString from it , it doesn't work of course :(

Comment: you can still use the way described in I_A_Mok's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41646555/2070636) below but it won't be a very good way to do what you want. See my updated answer for your other options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a large amount of data, you need to have SQL. If you want to use shared preference, you may try this:

```
private void saveBlood(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("uerInputBlood", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    listData.clear();
    editor.putInt("count", listData.size());
    for(int i=0; i<listData.size(); i++){
        editor.putString("blood"+i, listData.get(i));
    }
    editor.commit();
}


private void restoreBlood(){
    listData.clear();
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("uerInputBlood", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int tmpCount = preferences.getInt("count", 6);
    for(int i=0; i<tmpCount; i++){
        listData.add(preferences.getString("blood"+i, ""));
    }
}
```

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to the end of `onResume()`. You don't need it in`onCreate()` since you just created that adapter and the data did not change after.

Also, you don't need to call this part in both `onCreate()` and `onResume()`. Remove it from `onCreate()`. You are just adding the same item twice to your list that way:

```
String getUserInputBlood = preferences.getString("uerInputBlood", "");  
 listData.add(getUserInputBlood);
```

`SharedPreferences` are usually used to store a few key/value data items needed by your application. They are not intended for storing lists.

If you are trying to store all the list values, you should use some other form of data storage, e.g. a SQLite database. For more details, see [storage options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: I remove myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onCreate , and add it in onResume , but i put preferences=getSharedPreferences("uerInputBlood",MODE_PRIVATE); in onResume , it crash in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SqLite Database

In your case it would be much much easier to do it on SQLite than shared preferences.

Look at this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase

Glad to help you :-)

Comment: add this line after String uerInputBlood = editBloodSugar.getText().toString();         if(userInputBlood.equals("")){}else{  //write the rest here  }

Comment: Because if edittext output is null it will also cause the error